# R Postgres and shortcut commands?

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

Do postgres shortcuts like `\d+ tablename` work with `RPostgreSQL`?
If I try to run 'em I get a syntax error: Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "\d".

I tried escape it, but did not figure it out. `RPostgreSQL` itself works -- I can access and query my database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. These are "psql metacommands" and only recognised by the psql command-line interpreter. Only SQL commands can be passed through RPostgreSQL to the Postgres database.

Comment: You might want to try emulating the metacommands you need via queries to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=409471&seqNum=5